# 'Reuse' a single tensorflow model in different graphs?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow-slim

Currently, I am working with a pretrained VGG model in Tf-Slim library. My motivation is to generate adversarial examples for a given image for this netowrk. The summary of task is:

```
x= tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 32, 32,3), dtype=tf.float32)
for i in range(2):
    logits= vgg.vgg_16(x, is_training=False, spatial_squeeze=False, fc_conv_padding='SAME')
    x =  x + learning_rate*cal_gradient_of_logits_wrt_x(logits)
```

However, as soon we enter into the second iteration and start running logits= vgg.vgg16(....) we get the following error:

```
Variable vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/weights already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?
```

It is clear that this error occurred due to replication of graph in the second iteration. As the tf-slim model doesn't use `reuse=True` in the scopes, it throws this error (because in the second iteration we again ask it to add the vgg layers in the graph, which already exist).

**Is it possible to somehow avoid this error? It should be possible to create the graph for VGG model once and use it whenever we need to calculate logits.**

The reason this should be possible is the examples from keras. In keras we can simply define the model once with,

```
model= vgg.VGG16(*args, *kwargs)
```

Later on, we can add calculate logits for different tensor with,

```
logits_1= model(x1)
logits_2= model(x2)
```

Now in both these calculation, the same model parameters will be used i.e, no such error will appear. Is there a way to achieve the same functionality with a tensorflow model.

Answer (score 1):

In tfslim/models/research/slim/nets/vgg.py:

add a reuse parameter in the vgg16 or vgg19 definition

```
def vgg_16(inputs,
           num_classes=1000,
           is_training=True,
           dropout_keep_prob=0.5,
           spatial_squeeze=True,
           scope='vgg_16',
           fc_conv_padding='VALID',
           global_pool=False,
           reuse=None):
```

...
then set the variable scope to reuse the arg_scope if needed

```
with tf.variable_scope(scope, 'vgg_16', [inputs], reuse=reuse) as sc:
```

...

Then, when you invoke the function, pass the parameter as reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE

```
vgg.vgg_16(images, num_classes=dataset.num_classes,
           is_training=True, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf.make_template(func) to do this.

```
x= tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 32, 32,3), dtype=tf.float32)

vgg_model = tf.make_template(vgg.vgg_16, is_training=False, spatial_squeeze=False, fc_conv_padding='SAME')

for i in range(2):
  logits = vgg_model(x)
  x += learning_rate*cal_gradient_of_logits_wrt_x(logits)
```